# Multiprocessing / Process - How to manage the queue/manager?

Tags: python, multiprocess

Currently what I execute the job, then 3 processes will be started on the same time.

```
def someFunctionJob(x,y,**kwargs):
   ..... Code which will do some job

def manager(x,values):
    y = uuid.uuid4().hex
    pr = Process(target=someFunctionJob,args=(x,y,),kwargs=values)
    pr.start()

def main(x,values,settings):

    for i in settings:
        if xyz in ["abc"]:
            manager(x,values)
        elif lender in ["abc1"]:
           manager(lender,product)
        elif lender in ["abc2"]:
            manager(x,values)
```

What I need is that it will be managed by queue:

E.G. if `workers = 2`

The execution will be like this:

```
process 1
process 2
waiting till any of the processes will be finished
process 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  processes=[]
  for _ in range(2):
      p = Process(target=something )
      p.start()
      processes.append(p)

  for process in processes:
      process.join()
```

```
p = Process(target=something )
p.start()
```

What this code does is it executes 2 processes above then waits them finish and run another separate process.

Comment: For threading can I add parameters `t = threading.Thread(target=something,args=(x,y,),kwargs=values ) like this` ?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. If it is helpful accept my answer to help others also.

Comment: @ElvinJafarov sorry for the late reply was away and could not test it, the issue which I'm facing that it is not working as it should be as it keeps executing two jobs

Comment: @martineau do you have any suggestion or the source which I can read to learn this process more deeper?

Comment: @OksanaOk: Yes. I think what you need is either a [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://pymotw.com/3/multiprocessing/communication.html#process-pools) or a [`concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://pymotw.com/3/concurrent.futures/index.html#process-pools).